# How to SCP the output of a command from a remote server to another remote server?

Tags: linux, scp, file-server, remote-control

I am connected to a remote machine ( server1 ). On server1 I want to make a script that is copying & renaming some files that have a specific size but to rename them only after they are successfully copied, from another remote machine ( server2 ).
Example: Copy all the files with the size > 20k from a path from server2 to a path from server1

So I tried to make this script :

```
#!/bin/bash

#Connect on server2
ssh user@server2
#Go to the folder where the files I want to copy are located
cd /folder1/folder2/folder3
#Copy the files 
find . -maxdepth 1 -size +20k | scp * user@server1:<path_to_server1>
```

And that's where I got stuck. It seems that it doesn't get past the first line since it's asking me for a password to connect to server2. 
Also, I'm guessing that to rename them I need to do a for loop or something similar. Or is it another simpler way?
Can someone give me a hint to follow the right path?:)

I forgot to mention that on both servers I connect via public key

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: There are multiple problems here, and you'll have to sort them out one by one. To start with you say you connect with a public key, but the first line asks for a password.  Is it because you're trying to use a different account (`user`) ? Does this work when you execute the *exact* same command in an interactive shell? The second problem is even worse because it shows that you completely misunderstand how ssh works. When you do something like `ssh user@server2` in a script, without further arguments, it start *a new shell* on the server and doesn't return to your script until that shell exits.